# known_hosts has two hosts

Tags: ssh, unknown-host, ssh-keygen

I'm trying to delete a known_host with `ssh-keygen -R`, however, I have two hosts on one line, like this: `[slsapp.com]:1234,[108.163.203.146]:1234`. Should I just go in and do it by hand?

Answer (score 1):

Your client is clever and stores both hostname and IP address that the hostname resolves to (using DNS), which avoids additional verification when you in future connect to ip instead of host name.

If you changed host keys on server, you probably want to remove both of them, since both of them point to the same machine.